# What happens when I add multiple inline JavaScript functions to an onclick handler?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms, submit, synchronous

I simply want to know what happens in this case:

```
<input type="submit" name="a" id="b" value="Login" onclick="functionOne();functionTwo();" id="LoginUser_LoginButton">
```

Does `functionOne()` first run and then once it is completed, `functionTwo()` runs?

My actual situation is on a ASP.NET page, I'm trying to append a domain name to the username in a login page, before it gets submitted:

```
<input type="submit" name="LoginUser$LoginButton" id="loginSubmit" value="Login" onclick="appendDomain();javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;LoginUser$LoginButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;LoginUserValidationGroup&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="LoginUser_LoginButton">
```

Right now I have to way to test if appendDomain() is running before the form gets submitted, so I've got to verify this somehow without actually submitting the form. TIA!

Comment: The string you use for the value of an "onclick" handler works exactly as if the code appeared in a function; in fact what the browser does with that code is wrap it up as a JavaScript function.

Comment: You can not submit the form???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They will both run as if they were written in a JS block one after the other

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is exactly what happens. Unless your code does not execute any *asynchronous* operations, it will precisely execute in order.

However, it is considered as bad practice to inline Javascript code like that. You might want to use an unobtrusive solution by using `.addEventListener` for instance.